# how to solve Error in Entry module not found and in webpack in webpack.dev.js file?

Tags: angular, webpack

I have created a new app using webpack and added angular version 16, it's a custom webpack configuration. when I running the the same config from `webpack.dev.js` then it is working fine but when I create a common `webpack.common.js`and try to merge with `webpack.dev.js` file and trying to run then I am getting this error. Can someoe help me with this issue

Here are my files

webpack.common.js

```js
const path = require("path");
const helpers = require("./helper");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const { ContextReplacementPlugin } = require("webpack");
const { AngularWebpackPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = (options, argv) => {
    const isProd = !argv.env.WEBPACK_SERVE;
    const isDev = argv.env.WEBPACK_SERVE;

    return {
        entry: {
            pollyfills: ['/src/polyfills'],
            main: ['/src/main']
        },

        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.tsx'],

            modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

            alias: {
                "@app": path.resolve(helpers.root('src'), 'app'),
                "@configs": path.resolve(helpers.root('src'), 'configs')
            },
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.html$/i,
                    use: 'raw-loader',
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
                },

                {
                    test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif|eot|woff2|ttf)$i/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: isProd ? "[path][name].[hash].[ext]" : "[path][name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: "imgs"
                        }
                    }
                },

                {
                    test: /\.[cm]?js$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                            compact: false,
                            plugins: ['@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel'],
                        },
                    },
                },

                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
                },

                {
                    test: /\.(css|scss)$/i,
                    use: [
                        isDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader"
                        }
                    ],
                    include : [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
       * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
       * which changes every compilation.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
       */
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: 'corporate treasury',
                template: "src/index.html",
                gtmKey: '', // Google Tag Manager key
                minify: isProd
                    ? {
                        caseSensitive: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                        keepClosingSlash: true,
                        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                        removeComments: true
                    }
                    : false
            }),

            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: isDev ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
                chunkFilename: isDev ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
            }),

            new ContextReplacementPlugin(
                /angular(\\|\/)core/,
                helpers.root('src'),
                {}
            ),

            new AngularWebpackPlugin(),

            new DefinePlugin({
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            })
        ],
    }
}
```

webpack.dev.js

```js
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
const common = require('./webpack.common'); // the settings that are common to prod and dev

module.exports = () => {
    return merge(common, {
        mode: 'development',

        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            port: 8080
        },
    });
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "webpack-conf",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "this is the project has a custom configuration in angular",

    "keywords": [
        "angular",
        "angular2",
        "angular8",
        "angular16",
        "webpack",
        "typescript"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_ENV=dev webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --open src/",
        "build": "NODE_ENV=prod webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
        "server:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --no-inline --config webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/"
    },
  
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.13.1"
    },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1302.1",
            "@angular/cli": "^16.2.0",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
            "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.0",
            "@ngtools/webpack": "^16.2.0",
            "@types/core-js": "^2.5.5",
            "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.41",
            "@types/node": "^20.4.9",
            "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
            "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
            "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
            "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
            "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
            "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
            "install": "^0.13.0",
            "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
            "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
            "npm": "^9.8.1",
            "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
            "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
            "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
            "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
            "sass": "^1.64.2",
            "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
            "scss-loader": "0.0.1",
            "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
            "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
            "typescript": "^4.9.5",
            "webpack": "^5.88.2",
            "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
            "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.1.1",
            "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
            "webpack-merge": "^5.9.0"
        }
    }
```

when I am starting the app using npm start then I am getting this error.

[image: Error message]

if I use the same config from webpack.dev.js it is working fine. what mistake I am making can someone please give me some suggestions.